# Got more RAM, site slower

Tags: linux, mysql, performance, openvz

I was running my site on 256MB of ram with 2 cores and it was running ok, but I decided to upgrade to 1GB and 4 cores but now my site is slow.. I mean it takes more then 22 seconds to load 1 page....

Here is my top out put:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 6737 mysql     20   0  947m  24m 2404 S 55.9  2.4   1:23.52 mysqld
 5529 apache    20   0  324m  38m 2772 S  2.0  3.7   0:01.18 httpd
```

And my free -m output and **SHOW PROCESSLIST**:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1024       1017          6          0          0        790
-/+ buffers/cache:        227        796



+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State                | Info                                             |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 356 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL                 | SHOW PROCESSLIST                                 |
| 365 | root | localhost | db   | Sleep   |    8 |                      | NULL                                             |
| 367 | root | localhost | db   | Sleep   |    3 |                      | NULL                                             |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Why is it doing this?

Comment: Is this a physical or a virtual server? I would not expect anybody to be deploying physical servers with so little RAM anymore.

Comment: You need gto install monitoring an gather information hen decide what to do.

Comment: It's a OpenVZ VPS.

Comment: You cut off the _interesting_ part of the `top` output!

Comment: enable slow query log in mysql

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a problem with your VPS provider.  Maybe you were moved onto another system that is oversubscribed (or you stayed on the same box and the CPUs you are getting are oversubscribed - or the box doesn't have enough memory so its swapping [ when I say the box, I mean the server, not your Virtual Machine ]